# Add props and transition when component is a fragment view

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, url-routing

I'm trying to make an app with vue.js and the extension vue-router, so in my main HTML page I have:

```
<router-view v-transition="test" transition-mode="out-in"></router-view>
```

But then I got the error

```
Attribute v-transition is ignored on component router-view because the component is a fragment instance.
```

For the component i use vueify and it look like that:

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <div class="blabla">
            blabla
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
        second div
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function() {
            return {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Do you know how I could add transition and props to my component with vue-router ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know that components need to be one unique div. So I wrapped it in a unique div and it's working.

```
<template>
    <div> <!-- this is important -->
        <nav>
            <div class="blabla">
                blabla
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            second div
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And v-transition change for `transition` in vue 1.0.